# Core graphics - Line using midpoint and angle

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I hope it is possible to draw a line using center point and angle. I need to draw the line to move along with a circle.But I couldn’t make it work. I am not getting any idea how could do this!I tried the following code to rotate the line by specified angle, it didn’t work. As I am fairly new, I couldn’t understand where I am making mistake!! [This is how it looks if I use the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmAoD.png)

```
- (void)drawThumbAtPoint:(CGPoint)sliderButtonCenterPoint inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

//Vertical line
CGPoint newPoint = [self convertPoint:sliderButtonCenterPoint toView:self];
CGFloat angleInRadians = (CGFloat)M_PI/180.0f * currentAngle;
CGFloat distance = 15;
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(newPoint.x + distance * sinf(angleInRadians), newPoint.y + distance * cosf(angleInRadians));

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
path.lineWidth = 10.f;
[path moveToPoint:sliderButtonCenterPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:point];
[[UIColor redColor] set];
[path stroke];
//  CGAffineTransform rot = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
//  [path applyTransform:rot];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

And,

```
CGPoint thumbCenterPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(context);
[self drawThumbAtPoint:thumbCenterPoint inContext:context];
```

Comment: You have to use cosf() for the x-coordinate and sinf() for the y-coordinate.

Comment: I thought I should reverse it to draw vertical line.. Is that wrong? @MartinR

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vertical line"? Perhaps you can provide a drawing what the line should look like.

Comment: http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/geeklets/modules/upload/attachments/thumbs/dcm600x500.jpg You see the white line filling outer circle? I want to have a line ahead of this circle.. Able to understand?

Comment: Is `sliderButtonCenterPoint` the center of the circle, or the current point on the circle line?

Comment: Current point on the circle line..

Comment: Then you should add `(-1)*distance*sinf(..)` to the x-coordinate and `distance*cosf(..)` to the y-coordinate. I can provide a more detailed answer later.

Comment: Thank you so much.. And I don’t understand why should we use -1.. Hope you will explain it in your detailed answer :)

Comment: I have added an answer. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unit vector with angle `alpha` to the x-axis is

```
(cos(alpha), sin(alpha))
```

Now you want to draw a line that is tangential to the circle line, so it is perpendicular to the line from the center of the circle to the point on the circle line.

To get a perpendicular vector, you add 90º = π/2 to the angle:

```
(cos(alpha + π/2), sin(alpha + π/2)) = (-sin(alpha), cos(alpha))
```

using basic trigonometric identities.

This (hopefully) explains why the endpoint of the line must be computed as

```
CGPointMake(newPoint.x - distance * sinf(angleInRadians), newPoint.y + distance * cosf(angleInRadians));
```

Comment: So the new point should be the center point of the circle, not the current point?

Comment: Martin Thank you so much, I made a mistake in finding the angle.. I was calculating the angle between previous point and current point.. Now its working as I expect it to be :D Thank U :D

Answer (score 0):

Here a similar solution in **Swift 4.1**:

```
    // adding progress line view:
    // progress: 360 circle degree <=> 100% progress 
    let currentAngle: CGFloat = (progress * 360 / 100) - 90
    let angleInRadians: CGFloat = currentAngle * CGFloat.pi / 180

    let radius: CGFloat = outerCircle.frame.width / 2 - 1.0
    let lineXPosition = outerCircle.center.x + radius * cos(angleInRadians)
    let lineYPosition = outerCircle.center.y + radius * sin(angleInRadians)

    let progressLineView = UIView(frame: .init(x: lineXPosition, y: lineYPosition, width: 1, height: 1))
    progressLineView.backgroundColor = .clear
    progressLineView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (progress * 360 / 100) * CGFloat.pi / 180)
    progressLineView.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0

    let progressLineSubView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    progressLineSubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    progressLineSubView.backgroundColor = .blue
    progressLineSubView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
    progressLineSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0
    progressLineView.addSubview(progressLineSubView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        progressLineSubView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressLineView.centerXAnchor),
        progressLineSubView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressLineView.centerYAnchor),
        progressLineSubView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0),
        progressLineSubView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8.0)
        ])
    addSubview(progressLineView)
```